# Summarize next level

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm having a simple data model:

- Sales: Store, Sales
- Stores: Store, Account, Manager

[image]

[Sampe file here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/86a2fl)

I want to compare the sale of each account with the sales of the account's manager.

While I know I can simply build a pivot with the Manager and the Account as rows and use `CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales]),ALL(Stores[Account])`, I'm looking for a solution that works even if the Manager is not part of the pivot table.

I figured I can find the manager's name on the fly with `FIRSTNONBLANK` - and then use `Sales_Manager:=CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales]),ALL(Stores[Account]),FILTER(Stores,Stores[Manager]=FIRSTNONBLANK(Stores[Manager],TRUE)))` - but that does not work.

Here is the current (wrong) result:

[image]

What would be the best way to calculate Sales_Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go... :)

```
=CALCULATE([Sales_Total], ALL(Stores), VALUES(Stores[Manager]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is your filter context. You are slicing by each account which is why you are not getting the 388 total.

Using a measure with CALCULATE can help you ignore the filter context and get you what you are looking for.

Another option is to not include the account in the pivot table.

Comment: I need to include the account in the table - and the question is how to ignore the filter context. My approach clearly does not work, but can't think of a better one... :-( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FILTER(Stores,Stores[Manager]=FIRSTNONBLANK(Stores[Manager],TRUE)))

Add an ALL around your Stores?

Comment: Tried that - it then returns the total of all select, regardless of the manager. :-(